# WordPress installation error while using apache24

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, web

I was trying to install WordPress on localhost but I am not using Xampp or Wampp. Instead of it I was trying to install it using Apache and MySQL separately. But when I ran the URL for the installation i.e. http://localhost/wordpress/  , it asked for the site title, username, and password. I filled the form data and clicked next button. But at the next screen no install button was appeared instead of it A blank screen appeared. I have attached a screenshot. Please let me know, whats the problem with it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable debug mode in your wp_config.php:

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );